# Best way to perform software testing

Tags: debugging, testing

I just finished (mostly) a major application that I've been working on for a little over a year (off and on). It is around 86k lines of code, 50k of those is from Visual Studio's auto-generated dataset. It's largely a GUI to interacting with the database, generating reports, etc. It deals with money and manages contracts so it is important for it to be as bug free as possible.

I've walked through the code, and ran the program myself. I, for the most part, cannot find more bugs. I am however, sure there are, I've just been working on the system so long I can't see them anymore. I know there are some, because of some intermittent issues I run across, but can never pinpoint.

How should I go about software testing in order to discover the remaining bugs?

Comment: "walked through the code"?  Does this mean you have no unit test code of any kind?

Comment: correct, it was an inherited legacy code, plus I don't know much about unit testing and since this is largely a database-integrated application it makes it more difficult. This application was written to replace an Access 95 program that was outsourced to india, given up on, and passed to me.

Comment: Now that sounds like a lot of fun!

Comment: Sounds like the job of an intern! :) Actually, it's not bad. It provides many interesting challenges. I have more problems with .NET databinding than I do with what came from India, since I've largely rewritten what they wrote.

Comment: Most of us have left databinding and manually load/adjust/reload datagrids since the databinding has been so buggy.

Comment: @Lucas B, yes, I know what you mean. The original code base used Databinding so I stuck with it. The more I've used it the more I realize that it wasn't such a good idea. There was a half-assed attempt a month or two ago to pull out the databinding and replace it with CRUD stuff that I could do TDD with, but the client complained about the cost/time and I was assigned to do some crisis coding for a few other projects. It's just kinda sat in the code base unused since then.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a little late, but have you heard of [Test-Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)?

There are lots of tests you could build to discover the "remaining" bugs:

1) Unit tests

2) Integration tests

3) Behavior/Business/Acceptance tests

You could always attend a [Developer Testing Bootcamp](http://www.construx.com/Page.aspx?nid=84&id=49) to get more ideas.

Comment: "A little late" is an understatement.

Comment: How would I integrate TDD on a largely Databound, GUI driven application?

Comment: You need to abstract the UI from the data.  Follow a pattern such as MVC (Model-View-Controller).  This allows you to test the Model & Controller where your business rules are.  You wouldn't write unit tests for the view.

Comment: It might be too late for that. Almost all database interaction is handled by .NET's databinding.

Comment: @Malfist You could still implement type 2 and 3 tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can involve some of your end users and do a beta test that way.  The less experience they have with the application until now, the more likely they are to try things you didn't think of.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't use TDD to write it.  Your best bet now is to add as many automated tests as possible to cover common scenarios.  That way, when you do find bugs, and there are ALWAYS bugs in programs, you can hopefully minimize the risk to the rest of the system when you fix them.

Comment: +1: "add as many automated tests as possible".  Start with the stuff that's easiest to specify and write tests for.  Move on to the hard stuff once you have a base of tests running.